# Alternative to negative margins

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm looking for an alternative to using negative margins because I know they aren't considered "cool", and that they're considered hacky.

I'm starting a new site in WordPress and I need to add two images to every page. The images have to be linked and the link has to be different on every page so I can't add the images to a menu or a widget.

When I add them to the content of the page they display below the header, but I need them inside the header. I've positioned them like so:

```
.enflag{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}

.zhflag{
  position:absolute;
  top:1%;
  right:1%;
}
```

And then I added a negative margin-top in the dev tools and they display inside the header where I need them, but I'm wondering if there's an alternative to using the negative margin.

This image shows what I'm doing. The English flag has the negative margin but the Chinese flag displays below the header because it's only got positioning, which places it inside the same div, not at the top of the page.

[image]

[Working Sample](http://rmbpay.com.au/tmp/)

Comment: You should add all the relevant code (both HTML and CSS).

Comment: See full code at [link](http://rmbpay.com.au/tmp/)

Comment: The problem is not reproducible in jsfiddle. I'm assuming that's because it's a WordPress site.

Comment: I don't have a problem with them as I know they're perfectly legitimate according to standards. I was wondering if there was an alternative. I thought there was something I could use, but couldn't remember what it was.

Comment: The problem also can't be reproduced in a snippet, again I'm assuming that because it's a WordPress site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with negative margins if used appropriately. It's all about using the right tool for the job. In this case you're doing it a bit wrong.

Firstly if positioning multiple elements say your flags to the top right you want to be able to easily add/remove them without adding CSS so wrap them in a container that's absolutely positioned instead of positioning each flag on it's own OR float a container to the right if it's appropriate.

HTML

```
<div class="flag-container">
    <img class="alignright size-full wp-image-19 zhflag" src="http://rmbpay.com.au/tmp/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Zh-Flag-s.png" alt="Chinese Language Button" width="50" height="35">
    <a href="http://rmbpay.com.au/tmp/"><img class="alignright size-full wp-image-18 enflag" src="http://rmbpay.com.au/tmp/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/british-flag-s.png" alt="English Language Button" width="50" height="35"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flag-container{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; 
    top: -65px;
}
```

And remove all the rules for `.zhflag` and `.enflag` as none of them are now needed.

It's probably be better to move the flag-container in a container with the nav that's relatively positioned and 100% wide so that things are grouped better and to avoid layering issues particularly in older browsers.

Comment: Why I say you're doing it wrong is you were making work for yourself by positioning each element on it's own when it was easier to do it for a group - also you should never use vertical negative margins for positioning something horizontally inline - that's usually an indication that you're stuffed up the maths somewhere :)

Comment: I'll have to go with that `top:-65px;` I still think the only reason this is happening is that the site is a WordPress one. Otherwise the positioning would display the images at the top of the screen rather than at the top of the div.

Comment: Oh when logged in the admin bar will cause any absolutely positioned elements to be offset by a bit because from memory it does something like padding the body to make up for the height it takes - you could remove that padding or possibly wrap all your template in a relatively positioned 100% wide container which I think should fix the issue by making your absolutely positioned elements relative to the relative container :)